# How to write technical offer?

Tags: negotiation, consulting, software, group-freelancing

I'm a freelancer, recently I got a client for a mobile app, the matter is I don't know how to write a technical offer for the app, can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by a technical offer. Perhaps this will help.

You write down what you are going to do, how long it will take, what the customer will get delivered at the end of it. This is your schedule of work and should be as detailed as you can manage it.

You then write a quote for how much money you would want to complete the schedule of work. This will show the total amount and the deposit required to start (and any applicable taxes).

If the customer then has a question like 'What framework will you use?' you reply as honestly and openly as you can, but the next time you write a schedule of work, you include that info too. In this way your quotes and work descriptions improve over time.

There is no single way to do this. There is no right or wrong way except in the final analysis of did you get the job or not.

I hope that helps,

Paul.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, do I have do go deep in technical details I mean how the app will look like or just write down what tools I'll be using to achieve the app ?

Comment: Only quick cause I happened to be online and looking at the time. No, you should not design the app before you get the job. You can certainly list the main functionality. If the customer has said I want it to let customers create a shopping list, you can write under the heading shopping list. add items, view item details, edit quantities, delete items, duplicate items, add to wish list etc etc. But only include things the customer has already asked for. Do not make up functionality, even if in your opinion that would be a good thing. Give them what they ask for, but do not do anything upfront

Comment: Even the tools you use are not needed. Imagine you asked a carpenter for a new kitchen. He would not list the hammer and drill type. Just say what you are going to build and what you will deliver.